# JQuery-Resizable Library Issue - divs not resizing but splitters showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$("#blocklyArea").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 });
 
 $("#output").resizable({
   handleSelector: ".splitter-horizontal",
   resizeWidth: false
 });
```

```css
  .splitter {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      width: 18px;  
      background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/vsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
      min-height: 200px;
      cursor: col-resize;  
    }

    .splitter-horizontal {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      height: 18px;
      background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RickStrahl/jquery-resizable/master/assets/hsizegrip.png) center center no-repeat #535353;
      cursor: row-resize;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-resizable@1.0.6/resizable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-resizable-columns@0.2.3/dist/jquery.resizableColumns.min.js"></script>

<div style="display: flex; width: 100%; height: 400px;">

  <div id="blocklyArea" style="flex: 0 0 60%;"></div>
  <div id="blocklyDiv" style="position: absolute;"></div>

   <div class="splitter"></div>

  <div id="rightContainer" style="flex: 0 0 40%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div id="output" style="flex: 0 0 60%;">
      <pre id="outputCode"></pre>
    </div>

    <div class="splitter-horizontal"></div>

    <div id="bottomContainer" style="flex: 0 0 40%; position: relative;">
      <div class="tabsContainer" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('jscode')">jscode</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('pycode')">pycode</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('luacode')">luacode</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('dartcode')">dartcode</button>
        <button class="tabButton" onclick="openTab('phpcode')">phpcode</button>
      </div>
      <div id="jscode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;"><pre id="jscodePre"></pre></div>
      <div id="pycode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;"><pre id="pycodePre"></pre></div>
      <div id="luacode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;"><pre id="luacodePre"></pre></div>
      <div id="dartcode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;"><pre id="dartcodePre"></pre></div>
      <div id="phpcode" class="tab" style="height: 100%;"><pre id="phpcodePre"></pre></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

In the above code, I am attempting to create a vertical splitter between the two side-by-side divs, and another between the top and bottom divs in the right column. The splitters show fine so I believe my HTML and CSS to be fine. However, the splitters will not drag. I get no errors. I feel that the library is not perhaps loading correctly but I believe I have loaded them OK.

Any help would be gratefully receieved.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for jquery resizable columns:

```
 <script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/store.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.resizableColumns.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered" data-resizable-columns-id="demo-table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th data-resizable-column-id="#">#</th>
    <th data-resizable-column-id="first_name">First Name</th>
    <th data-resizable-column-id="last_name">Last Name</th>
    <th data-resizable-column-id="username" data-noresize>Username</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  ...
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("table").resizableColumns({
    store: window.store
  });
});
</script>
```

and this is for jquery resizable:

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
```

I think you mixed up these two libraries

```
{
   handleSelector: ".splitter",
   resizeHeight: false
 }
```

according to https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/